# Parameter from popup in PowerCenter?

Tags: etl, informatica-powercenter

I'm starting in the next powercenter and I doubt there is a transformation where I can enter a parameter for some command or popup ?

For example some reports for the client wants to enter the date .

Thanxs

Comment: Shouldn't this be a filter in the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no transformation in PowerCenter that can do that, because PowerCenter is mostly used as a batch processing tool.

However, if you need to change some parameters before each execution,  you can do so using a parameter file.

Comment: I can generate from an Oracle table parameter file ?

Comment: Informatica accepts parameter file in it's own specific format. The parameter file path can be specified in the workflow or session properties. If you store your parameters in a Oracle table, you have build some process to write those parameters in a Informatica parameter file.

Answer (score 0):

> For a different approach: simply you can have a source file where you
>   can put the date and you can use this source file to get the desired
>   date and use it ahead.